# display current system time using angularjs in html

Tags: html, angularjs, time

I want to display the current system time in the page i am making but it seems to be not working. i dont know why

```html
<script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="css/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular/angular-ui.js"></script>
```

another code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', [])
  app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $filter) {
    var date = new Date();
    $scope.ddMMyyyy = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy'); 
  });
</script>

<div ng-app="mymodal" ng-controller="MyController">
  <u>dd/MM/yyyy format</u><br /><span ng-bind = "ddMMyyyy"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: put `jquery` top of `angular.min.js`

Comment: its not working still :(

Comment: That's just suggession :P check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as given and include HH:mm:ss for time.

```
var mymodal = angular.module('mymodal', [])
      mymodal.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $filter) {
        var date = new Date();
        $scope.ddMMyyyy = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'); 
      });
```

Comment: hi @sansarp I want to use cgi for this. How can I possibly do that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @AnikIslamAbhi, there are two issues that need to be addressed.

1. `app` should be `mymodal` instead
2. put `jquery` before `angular`

After updating your code, it works correctly.

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pswai/xdnwg2xp/)

**Update**

However, a better practice is to not assign Angular module to a variable. Instead, use `angular.module()` to get a module.

```js
// This declares a module (note the second parameter)
angular.module('MyModule', []);

// This retrieves a module    
angular
  .module('MyModule')
  .controller('MyController', function() {});

// Module declaration can be chained with controllers, filters, etc.
angular
  .module('AnotherModule', [])
  .controller('AnotherController', function() {})
  .filter('AnotherFilter', function() {});
```

Checkout [the developer guide on modules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).